# Не видит описание типа

Tags: stm32

Проект передачи данных при помощи nRF24l01 мозгом является микроконтроллере stm32f303vc. Проект с ошибкой в IAR прикрепляю к посту.

Описание типа nRF24L01 dev есть в заголовочном файле, но почему то не хочет его от туда подхватывать.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ann2CRUC07O4gZgEYDlWNkq2kJRfHg

Comment: Выложите нерабочий код здесь. Не нужно прикреплять файлы.

Comment: И добавьте метку языка. [tag:stm32] - не самая популярная метка.